# convert sql server AlphaToDate4 to oracle date which has 5 numbers

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Hi good day I have the following code I am trying to convert from sql server to oracle, It works perfectly on sql but not on oracle. How can I convert the ff?

This is the code from sql

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR, RLL.dbo.AlphaToDate4(A.DATE_R), 103) CaptureDate
from Employees
```

This is the format of Date_R (78684)

I am trying to write the following code in oracle but gives me an error

```
select TO_DATE((A.DATE_R),'DD/MM/YYYY')  CAPTUREDATE
```

Comment: Can you please better explain the format you have? That is, what does 78684 mean and why?

Comment: `RLL.dbo.AlphaToDate4` is clearly a user defined scalar function, so we have no access to know what value is returned for `RLL.dbo.AlphaToDate4(A.DATE_R)`. You've also not posted the error from Oracle, making this even harder for others to debug. Posting some sample data and expected results will greatly help the uses here.

Comment: the column Date_R is a keydate and is a number format (78684), so I am trying to convert it in oracle

Comment: `select to_char(date'1800-01-01' + 78684, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual` = `2015-06-07`?

Comment: ok, but how to interpret this numeric format? Which date does 78684 represent?

Comment: CaptureDate DATE_R
04/06/2015 78682
04/06/2015 78682
04/06/2015 78682
04/06/2015 78682
04/06/2015 78682

Comment: Andrei yes when you convert "78684" it becomes '2015-06-07'

Comment: Thanks @AndreiOdegov it worked  your query worked

Comment: @user2260994, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your number represents the number of days from 31/12/1799 (are you sure?), you may need to add the column value to this date, that is

```
select date '1799-12-31' + date_R
```

If you need a formatted string:

```
select to_char( date '1799-12-31' + date_R, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```